# library for light-weight wallet : btcsuite or BitcoinJ

Tags: lightning-network, bitcoinj, compact-client-side-block-filters

Do **btcsuite** + **Neutrino**(Lightning-lab) together provide sufficient foundation for light client capable to service onchain transactions (not multisig & not related to Payment Channels)?

Or is it possible to use Neutrino in conjunction with **BitcoinJ** to replace its Bloom filters?

The app will focus on bitcoin onchain transactions, but in future we'd like to do Lightning transactions also.